# Why is a stock trade flat on large volume?

Tags: stocks, online-trading

I am looking at a company which has recently a strong spike up following good news.
After several days of small pullbacks the stock is flat but the daily volume is high compared to average.

When I say that the stock is flat I mean it trades between 19.68 and 19.71 (for the whole day)
How to interpret such a situation?

Comment: Beyond the basics of supply and demand, what else is there here?

Answer (score 1):

Large volume just means a lot of market participants believe they know where the stock price will be (after some amount of time).  The fact that the price is not moving just means that about 50% of those really confident traders think the stock will be moving up, and about 50% of those really confident traders think the stock will be moving down.